# Full video background using video.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm trying to make a full screen video background that always shows the full size even on window resize.

here it's the site:
http://webkunst.comeze.com/test/

this is the problem I have:

on wide screen it shows like this:
http://webkunst.comeze.com/test/wide.png

and on vertical screen it shows like this:
http://webkunst.comeze.com/test/vertical.png

As you can see it always put some black bars to the video instead of resizing the video to the full of the screen.

This is my markup:

```
           <div id="full-background">
                <video class="video-js vjs-fullscreen"  autoplay preload="auto"  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" data-setup="{}">
                    <source src="video/1.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
                </video>
            </div>
```

with this css:

```
#full-background {
  z-index: -999;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


.video-js.vjs-fullscreen {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  _position: absolute;
  /* IE6 Full-window (underscore hack) */

}
```

I'm using the video.js plugin:
http://videojs.com/

Any ideas and how to make the video full size without showing black bars on the side or top/bottom?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [BigVideo.JS](http://dfcb.github.com/BigVideo.js/)? 
It uses Video.JS as the core and builds on top of it. It only requires jQuery.

Comment: BigVideo seems like a solution. There is an undocumented 'container' option that allows you to use it on a particular div.

Comment: @mikemaccana WOW, you just saved me a lot of headache.  I was looking at using bigvideo.js and already had my container all prepped and styled, but was about to drop it and go to vanilla videojs instead.  Why they don't put this option on the website is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can only specify the default video width and height here:

http://videojs.com/tag-builder/

but **you can't** stretch the video itself to fill the different screen resolutions, it always maintains the aspect ratio.

But instead of black bars you can specify color:

```
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-play-progress { background: #900; }
```

or Skin:

```
<video class="video-js my-custom-skin" ...>
```

Source: https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/skins.md

Comment: thanks for the answer but I hope I find a solution to get it full.

Comment: Please post back if you find any solution outside.

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries to apply different CSS Classes depending upon the aspect ratio?

I'm using a widescreen laptop and can get the video to be full screen by using the following.

```
.video-js .vjs-tech {
width: 100% !important;
}

video {
    width:100%;
}
```

For a portrait screen I can get it to fill the height by using the following.

```
.video-js .vjs-tech {
height:100% !important
}

video {
width:auto !important;
}
```

So you could use the media queries like `@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9)` to apply the different dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Use object-fit. Don't forget to set a height for the parent div.

```
 .video-js {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .video-js .vjs-tech {
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```